# How do I fix this problem? im new to Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I keep coming across errors that I've linked in the photos below. I'm fairly new to javascript and can't find anything online about this. I'm just starting out so details would be heavily appreciated. Thank you so much for your time and help :) (I'm having to add more details because the amount of code)(I'm having to add more details because the amount of code)

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFAZQ.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5w6m.png)

```
var onePiece = 0;
var deathNote = 0;
var haikyuu = 0;
var fruitsBasket = 0;

var questionCount = 0;


//question 1
var q1a1 = document.getElementById("q1a1");
var q1a2 = document.getElementById("q1a2");
var q1a3 = document.getElementById("q1a3");
var q1a4 = document.getElementById("q1a4");
//question 2
var q2a1 = document.getElementById("q2a1");
var q2a2 = document.getElementById("q2a2");
var q2a3 = document.getElementById("q2a3");
var q2a4 = document.getElementById("q2a4");
//question 3
var q3a1 = document.getElementById("q3a1");
var q3a2 = document.getElementById("q3a2");
var q3a3 = document.getElementById("q3a3");
var q3a4 = document.getElementById("q3a4");
//question 4
var q4a1 = document.getElementById("q4a1");
var q4a2 = document.getElementById("q4a2");
var q4a3 = document.getElementById("q4a3");
var q4a4 = document.getElementById("q4a4");
//question 5
var q5a1 = document.getElementById("q5a1");
var q5a2 = document.getElementById("q5a2");
var q5a3 = document.getElementById("q5a3");
var q5a4 = document.getElementById("q5a4");

// // Listen for click
//question 1
q1a1.addEventListener("click", onePiece);
q1a2.addEventListener("click", deathNote);
q1a3.addEventListener("click", haikyuu);
q1a4.addEventListener("click", fruitsBasket);
//question 2
q2a1.addEventListener("click", fruitsBasket);
q2a2.addEventListener("click", haikyuu);
q2a3.addEventListener("click", deathNote);
q2a4.addEventListener("click", onePiece);
//question 3
q3a1.addEventListener("click", deathNote);
q3a2.addEventListener("click", onePiece);
q3a3.addEventListener("click", fruitsBasket);
q3a4.addEventListener("click", haikyuu);
//question 4
q4a1.addEventListener("click", haikyuu);
q4a2.addEventListener("click", deathNote);
q4a3.addEventListener("click", onePiece);
q4a4.addEventListener("click", fruitsBasket);
//question 5
q5a1.addEventListener("click", onePiece);
q5a2.addEventListener("click", deathNote);
q5a3.addEventListener("click", haikyuu);
q5a4.addEventListener("click", fruitsBasket);


// Track score and check if quiz is complete 
function onePiece() {
    onePiece += 1;
    questionCount += 1;

  console.log("questionCount =" + questionCount + "onePiece =" + onePiece);

  if (questionCount == 5) {
    console.log("You have finished the quiz!")
    updateResult();
  }
}

function deathNote() {
  deathNote += 1;
  questionCount += 1;

  console.log("questionCount =" + questionCount + "deathNote =" + deathNote);

  if (questionCount == 5) {
    console.log("You have finished the quiz!")
    updateResult();
  }
}

function haikyuu() {
  haikyuu += 1;
  questionCount += 1;

  console.log("questionCount =" + questionCount + "haikyuu =" + haikyuu);

  if (questionCount == 5) {
    console.log("You have finished the quiz!")
    updateResult();
  }
}

function fruitsBasket() {
  fruitsBasket += 1;
  questionCount += 1;

  console.log("questionCount =" + questionCount + "fruitsBasket =" + fruitsBasket);

  if (questionCount == 5) {
    console.log("You have finished the quiz!")
    updateResult();
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of your codes, paste it as a text

Comment: in the onePeice function you have incremented a onePeice variable by one. Is that variable is gloabal? I mean did you define any variable onePeice before add eventListener?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Sorry about that, I've updated it.

Comment: @Nav I did define the variable at the beginning, I'm just learning so I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong. I went ahead and updated it so it shows all my code, please let me know if this helps, thank you!

Comment: @srhxx  try changing the names of the callback functions in addEventListeners. Make them something different than the variable names. It should work

Answer (score 0):

`Error 1` is probably a problem with replit devtools - It doesn't really matter

`Error 2` may be caused by the functions being after the `addEventListener`

I am not that experienced in js so this might not be the problem

Also, as Geeky Quentin said, post the code as text, not an image.

You can use ```` ``` ```` for multiline code like this:

````
 ```
Code here
 ```
````

Comment: Usually you are allowed to define the functions wherever you want, but with some conditions.
However it is wrong in this case, as the variable with same name as that of the function have been defined on the top of the eventListener. So javascript instead of searching for a callback function, is sending the variable to the second argument to the function.

Comment: However, eventListener is expecting a function, but it is getting a variable hence the error